# WordPress/WooCommerce: Save custom payment post meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am using a plugin that is creating a custom payment type where the user can fill in a custom payment ID. The thing is, I want that custom payment ID stored in an ACF field as post meta on the WooCommerce order edit page. I have created an ACF field named 'kkpayment' for this task. I figured the rest should be done using `update_field($selector, $value, [$post_id]);`. I have created a PHP function for this task. However, my code doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something obvious?

My function for updating the ACF field:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_payment_update_order_meta_acf' );
function custom_payment_update_order_meta_acf( $order_id ) {
$transaction = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'transaction', true );

    if($_POST['payment_method'] = 'custom')
        return $transaction;

    update_field('kkpayment', $transaction, $order_id);
    
}
```

The custom payment is made with this code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: KK Payment Gateway
Description: Modtag betaling med kontostreng
Author: Arvin Aliari & Tobias Hyrup
Author URI: https://aliari.dk
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

/**
 * Baseret på StackOverlow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081483/custom-payment-method-in-woocommerce
 *
 * Tilpasninger til dette projekt, se linje 135 - 161
 *
 *
 *
 * Custom Payment Gateway.
 *
 * Provides a Custom Payment Gateway.
 */
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'init_custom_gateway_class');

function init_custom_gateway_class(){

    class WC_Gateway_Custom extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

        public $domain;

        /**
         * Constructor for the gateway.e Number
         */
        public function __construct() {

            $this->domain = 'custom_payment';

            $this->id                 = 'custom';
            $this->icon               = apply_filters('woocommerce_custom_gateway_icon', '');
            $this->has_fields         = false;
            $this->method_title       = __( 'Prisme', $this->domain );
            $this->method_description = __( 'Tag i mod betaling fra Prisme.', $this->domain );

            // Load the settings.
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();

            // Define user set variables
            $this->title        = $this->get_option( 'title' );
            $this->description  = $this->get_option( 'description' );
            $this->instructions = $this->get_option( 'instructions', $this->description );
            $this->order_status = $this->get_option( 'order_status', 'completed' );

            // Actions
            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'thankyou_page' ) );

            // Customer Emails
            add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', array( $this, 'email_instructions' ), 10, 3 );
        }

        /**
         * Initialise Gateway Settings Form Fields.
         */
        public function init_form_fields() {

            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title'   => __( 'Aktiver/Deaktiver', $this->domain ),
                    'type'    => 'checkbox',
                    'label'   => __( 'Tillad betaling med kontostreng', $this->domain ),
                    'default' => 'yes'
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Titel', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => __( 'Angiver den titel som brugeren ser under checkout.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => __( 'Betaling med kontostreng', $this->domain ),
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
                'order_status' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Ordrestatus', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'select',
                    'class'       => 'wc-enhanced-select',
                    'description' => __( 'Vælg hvilken status du ønsker efter chekout.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => 'wc-completed',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                    'options'     => wc_get_order_statuses()
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Beskrivelse', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'description' => __( 'Beskrivelse af betalingsmetoden som brugerene ser under chekout.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => __('Payment Information', $this->domain),
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
                'instructions' => array(
                    'title'       => __( 'Instruktioner', $this->domain ),
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'description' => __( 'Besked som brugerene vil se på efter gennemført ordre.', $this->domain ),
                    'default'     => '',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
            );
        }

        /**
         * Output for the order received page.
         */
        public function thankyou_page() {
            if ( $this->instructions )
                echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->instructions ) );
        }

        /**
         * Add content to the WC emails.
         *
         * @access public
         * @param WC_Order $order
         * @param bool $sent_to_admin
         * @param bool $plain_text
         */
        public function email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text = false ) {
            if ( $this->instructions && ! $sent_to_admin && 'custom' === $order->payment_method && $order->has_status( 'on-hold' ) ) {
                echo wpautop( wptexturize( $this->instructions ) ) . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }

        public function payment_fields(){

            if ( $description = $this->get_description() ) {
                echo wpautop( wptexturize( $description ) );
            }

            ?>
            <div id="custom_input">
              <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="transaction" class=""><?php _e('26-cifret kontostreng:', $this->domain); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" class="" name="transaction" id="transaction" placeholder="12345-1234-123-123456789-123-12" value="" style="width: 225px;">
                </p>
                <p style="opacity: 0.75; margin-top:-10px; font-size: 13.5px;">Eks: 12345-1234-123-123456789-123-12</p>
                <p>Hvis du ikke har en kontostreng, så kontakt din nærmeste leder eller økonomimedarbejder.</p>
            </div>
            <?php
        }


        public function validate_fields(){

            $paymentString = $_POST['transaction'];
            $strLength = strlen($paymentString);

            /*$stringContains = preg_match("/^\d{5}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{7}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{2}$/", $paymentString);*/

            $stringContains = preg_match("/^\d{5}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{9}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{2}$/", $paymentString);
            if($stringContains && !empty($_POST['transaction']) && $_POST['transaction'] != "") {
                return true;
            } else  {
                $stringOldPattern = preg_match("/^\d{5}[-]\d{4}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{7}[-]\d{3}[-]\d{2}$/", $paymentString);
                if($stringOldPattern){
                    wc_add_notice(  "Ugyldig kontostreng - Husk at bruge det nye format på 26 cifre der inkluderer funktionskode. Tjek at du har indtastet kontostrengen korrekt. Eksempel: 12345-1234-123-123456789-123-12", 'error' );
                } else  {
                    wc_add_notice(  "Ugyldig kontostreng - Tjek at du har indtastet kontostrengen korrekt. Eksempel: 12345-1234-123-123456789-123-12", 'error' );
                }
                return false;
            }
        }


        /**
         * Process the payment and return the result.
         *
         * @param int $order_id
         * @return array
         */
        public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

            $status = 'wc-' === substr( $this->order_status, 0, 3 ) ? substr( $this->order_status, 3 ) : $this->order_status;

            // Set order status
            $order->update_status( $status, __( 'Checkout with custom payment. ', $this->domain ) );

            // Reduce stock levels
            $order->reduce_order_stock();

            // Remove cart
            WC()->cart->empty_cart();

            // Return thankyou redirect
            return array(
                'result'    => 'success',
                'redirect'  => $this->get_return_url( $order )
            );
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_custom_gateway_class' );
function add_custom_gateway_class( $methods ) {
    $methods[] = 'WC_Gateway_Custom';
    return $methods;
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'process_custom_payment');
function process_custom_payment(){

    if($_POST['payment_method'] != 'custom')
        return;


    if( !isset($_POST['transaction']) || empty($_POST['transaction']) )
        //wc_add_notice( __( 'Angiv venligst dit 26-cifret kontostreng til Prisme', $this->domain ), 'error' );
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Angiv venligst dit 26-cifret kontostreng til Prisme', ), 'error' );

}

/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_payment_update_order_meta' );
function custom_payment_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    if($_POST['payment_method'] != 'custom')
        return;

    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($_POST);
    // echo "</pre>";
    // exit();

    
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'transaction', $_POST['transaction'] );
}

/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    $method = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method', true );
    if($method != 'custom')
        return;

    $transaction = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'transaction', true );

    echo '<p><strong>'.__( '26 cifret kontostreng').':</strong> ' . $transaction . '</p>';
}



/**
 * Add payment to metadata
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_payment_update_order_meta_acf' );
function custom_payment_update_order_meta_acf( $order_id ) {
$transaction = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'transaction', true );

    if($_POST['payment_method'] = 'custom')
        return $transaction;

    update_field('kkpayment', $transaction, $order_id);
    
}
```

Comment: You seem to be returning `$transaction` if `payment_method` is `custom`. You don't want to save the field when method is `custom`?

Comment: I do want to save the field when the method is custom... I guess I would need != 'custom' then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to update acf field on successful transaction.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bks_post_transaction_after_order_completion', 10, 1 );

function bks_post_transaction_after_order_completion( $order_id ) {
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // phpcs:ignore.
$status = $order->get_status();

// Try to post only when order status is completed or processing.
if ( ! ( 'completed' === $status || 'processing' === $status ) ) {
return;
}

// get transaction.
$transaction = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'transaction', true );

update_field('kkpayment', $transaction, $order_id);
$order->update_meta_data( 'kkpayment', $transaction ); // phpcs:ignore
$order->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Bhanu! Your comments make sense. However, it doesn't seem to work. ACF field is empty when placing an order :(

Comment: Try one thing. just beneath `$transaction`. Add `var_dump($_POST['payment_method'])` and check if comes out to be custom or not and beneath dump add `die()`.  Make a test payment. The only explanation can be that the meta tag is incorrect or the code never goes inside if clause because the method isn't custom. If this doesn't output anything then you can be sure that your hook is not being hit only and then can start to debug.

Comment: After adding var_dump and die() I am not able to place an order. I get error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. However, the plugin I am using is working just fine where the unique payment ID is being placed in order edit page with this line: ```echo '<p><strong>'.__( '26 cifret kontostreng').':</strong> ' . $transaction . '</p>';.``` I just need the value to be stored in some sort of post meta.

Comment: @TurboTobias remove the if case and directly hit `update_field`

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Do you have to save this data when the order gets completed, correct ? @TurboTobias

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233244/discussion-between-bhanu-and-turbotobias).

Comment: @TurboTobias, consider marking this as an answer if it helped.